# Boot2Docker: Persist bash function

Tags: boot2docker

I'm running the Boot2Docker ISO under Hyper-V on Windows and mount a host folder via `sudo mkdir /mnt/www && sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlm,username=docker,pass=docker //192.168.137.1/www /mnt/www'`. This is the folder which is used by the docker container.
I would like to have the mount command in the `.ashrc` so I don't have to type the whole command each time I restart the VM. Is there a way to persist the `.asrc` in Boot2Docker? Or better to have it mounted via it boots?

Comment: I am trying this too.   All the changes I make are either disallowed or they only persist until the VM is stopped.  I have modified `/opt/bootlocal.sh` as recommended by others but my changes get wiped by the next stop/start sequence.